# General solution to system of equations in matrix form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the system of equations x' in the following matrix:

$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

I believe that it is correct to interpret this as -x = 0 and y=0, which would yield a fixed point at (0,0). But can a Jacobian be found from this information with which I could find the stability of the fixed point and origin?

Comment: How about finding the solution as the first statement says? You can see the eigenvalues immediately. What do those tell you about stability of the fixed point? This matrix gives us the system $$x' = -x, y' = y$$ This is easy to solve and clearly the fixed point is $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Moo perhaps my algebra is rusty, but that is what I am confused over. As you say, x'=-x and y'=y. But how does one find a general solution from this limited information?

Comment: How do you solve $x' = -x$? How do you solve $y' = y$? These two equations are decoupled and can be solve by inspection. Clear?

Comment: I was thinking about it all wrong. Very clear. Thank you.